# inserting unique data in the table by php file

Tags: php, mysql

```
create table member(
member_id int not null auto_increment,
member_name varchar(50) not null,
look_contact_number int(4) default 5,
primary key(member_id)
)

create table contact_viewed(
contact_viewed_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
contacted_member_id int (11) not null,
member_id int(11) not null,
primary key(contact_viewed_id)
);
```

I want to insert data in the `contact_viewed` table where `member_id` can be same, it means one member can see multiple contacts but `contacted_member_id` should be unique.

I am using request param id by the url see below

```
/contact_viewed.php?id=1;
```

First I have taken condition if `member_id=2` don't have data in the table member then insert the data in the table, then I have checked by `rowCount()` method if `member_id=2` in member table have data then check `contacted_member_id` is available in database or not, if available then do nothing, if not available then insert the data into the database.

My problem is when `foreach` loop is executing then it is inserting data where `id != contacted_member_id`,if any one have idea so please help me.

```
<?php
    $stmt7 = $DB_con->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM contact_viewed WHERE member_id=:member_id" );
    $stmt7->bindParam ( ":member_id", $m_id );
    $stmt7->execute ();
    $row2 = $stmt7->fetchAll ();
    if ($stmt7->rowCount () > 0) {
    foreach ( $row2 as $data ) {
            if ($data ['member_id'] == $m_id) {
                if($data ['contacted_member_id'] == $_GET['id']){
                    echo "do nothing1";
                }
                else{
                    $stmt6 = $DB_con->prepare ( "INSERT INTO contact_viewed(contacted_member_id,member_id) VALUES(:contacted_member_id,:member_id)" );
                    $stmt6->bindParam ( ":contacted_member_id", $_GET ['id'] );
                    $stmt6->bindParam ( ":member_id", $m_id );
                    $stmt6->execute ();
                    echo "hello";
                }
            } 
        } 
    }
    else{
        $stmt6 = $DB_con->prepare ( "INSERT INTO contact_viewed(contacted_member_id,member_id) VALUES(:contacted_member_id,:member_id)" );
        $stmt6->bindParam ( ":contacted_member_id", $_GET ['id'] );
        $stmt6->bindParam ( ":member_id", $m_id );
        $stmt6->execute ();
        $available_contact = $userRow ['available_contact'];
        $available_contact = $available_contact - 1;
        $stmt5 = $DB_con->prepare ( "UPDATE member SET available_contact=:available_contact WHERE member_id=:member_id" );
        $stmt5->bindParam ( ":available_contact", $available_contact );
        $stmt5->bindParam ( ":member_id", $m_id );
        $stmt5->execute ();
        echo "ok ok";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Just an FYI (probably won't solve your issue), the PDO manual notes that `rowCount()` is not reliable on `SELECT` statements and suggests not to use it in that instance. Using a `COUNT()` statement is preferred for select.

Comment: @Rasclatt thanks for your response,it is very helpful for me,Sir If i will send my code can you please check it once,can I have your email id

Comment: You want me to give you my email so you can send me your code? Is that what you are proposing?

Comment: yes i want your email id to send code

Comment: Sorry, no. I can not review your code. I don't know anything about you or how your hosting is set up. I don't know if you are going to spam me, or what-have-you. Sorry. I can only help you through SO for now.

Comment: Your name doesn't have anything to do with it, I just won't give out my email to just anyone, but I can still help via SO if you are still having problems.

Comment: yes still i have problem but i am trying by itself,actually i have spent lots of time in that that's why i asked question on stack overflow.

Comment: Well one piece of advice I could give is to create a query class (or separate functions) so you don't have to repeat all your code so much. Anytime you have to number your statements, usually means you could do it better.

Comment: Are you familiar with setting up classes and/or functions?

Comment: No I have 1 month of experience in php and mysql

Comment: Ok well give me a second, I will give you an example, but it may not fix what you are trying to do but it may give you a better idea of what I mean.

Comment: ok sure sir,i will get some  new concept

Comment: It looks like you have an answer based on your code, make sure you look into reducing all your statements/executing and such with the use of functions or a class, your code will benefit a lot from it. Good luck!

Comment: @Rasclatt,Thanks Sir, I have get idea by you and shift all my code class and function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $stmt7 = $DB_con->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM contact_viewed WHERE member_id=:member_id AND contacted_member_id=:contacted_member_id" );
    $stmt6->bindParam ( ":contacted_member_id", $_GET ['id'] );
    $stmt7->bindParam ( ":member_id", $m_id );
    $stmt7->execute ();
    $row2 = $stmt7->fetchAll ();
    if ($stmt7->rowCount () == 0) {
        $stmt6 = $DB_con->prepare ( "INSERT INTO contact_viewed(contacted_member_id,member_id) VALUES(:contacted_member_id,:member_id)" );
        $stmt6->bindParam ( ":contacted_member_id", $_GET ['id'] );
        $stmt6->bindParam ( ":member_id", $m_id );
        $stmt6->execute ();
        $available_contact = $userRow ['available_contact'];
        $available_contact = $available_contact - 1;
        $stmt5 = $DB_con->prepare ( "UPDATE member SET available_contact=:available_contact WHERE member_id=:member_id" );
        $stmt5->bindParam ( ":available_contact", $available_contact );
        $stmt5->bindParam ( ":member_id", $m_id );
        $stmt5->execute ();
        echo "ok ok";
    }
```

Comment: @Jevgenjis Sulins,Thanks for your response,Thanks it is working as i want